# How to draw a line on the bar close when the condition is met in Pine Script?

Tags: plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I continuously draw a line on bar close when the condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot with valuewhen.

Example:
condition=ta.cross(ta.sma(close,20),ta.sma(close,50))
v=ta.valuewhen(condition,close,0)
plot(v)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain further, what exactly you want to do?

- If you want to draw a line from one point, to another you can use `line.new()`, which could look like this:

```
if condition
  line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

- If you want to draw a series on a given condition you can use `plot()` and the ternary operator `?:`, which could look like this:

```
plot(condition ? value : na) // if condition, then plot value, else plot na (like null)
```